# Google API Console - sites service

Tags: api, console, sites

There is no entry for sites as a service in the google api console, but it is possible to select it in the google oauth playground.

How can I obtain a client-id and client-secret to use the google sites api?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the admin-sdk service; but I'm still trying to work this out myself. In the oauth playground, you're selecting the scope not the service.